# No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document 6

Tags: android, xml, constraints

I am making my exam in programming C on my gymnasium. My App chrashes every time i click on either "krypter" or "dekrypter" (they are two buttons).
I get the above error in some diffent places in my code and cant figure out what the problem is. I have already looked at many other questions like this but none made me see the problem.
The two activites is mostly identical and the same for the XML's.

The code for one of the activities you can open from my main activity

```
public class Krypteringstype extends Activity {

public Button slider;
public Button krypterKnap;
public EditText tekst;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.krypteringstype);                               // viser krypteringssiden
    slider = (Button) findViewById(R.id.handle);                            // forbinder xml-knappen og knappen "slider", som er defineret tidligere
    slider.getBackground().setAlpha(230);                                   // gør baggrunden, som jeg bruger let transparent
    //tekst = (EditText) findViewById(editText1);
    krypterKnap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.krypter);
    krypterKnap.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            krypterKnap();
        }
    });
}

private void krypterKnap() {
    if (tekst.getText().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Skriv tekst først", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        konverter();
    }   
}

private void konverter(){
    String initialString = "yourString";
    char[] chars = initialString.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i)
        chars[i] = (char)((int)chars[i] + 2);
//  String resultString = new String(chars);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.krypter, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

The XML for the activity above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/blue_binary_code_1600_1200"
tools:context=".Krypter" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/krypter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_large"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="35dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:text="@string/valg"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/standardKrypter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_large"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="35dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:text="@string/standard"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/overskriftKrypter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_large"
    android:minHeight="35dp"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:text="@string/overskrift"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/krypter"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/overskriftKrypter"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerKrypter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_large"
            android:minHeight="35dp"
            android:text="@string/ceasar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/ceasarNr"
                android:inputType="number" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_large"
            android:minHeight="35dp"
            android:text="@string/abe" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/a"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/b"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/e"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_large"
            android:minHeight="35dp"
            android:text="@string/rsa" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prim1"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prim2"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/k"
                android:inputType="number" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
</LinearLayout>
```

The code for the second activity you can open from my main activity

```
public class Dekrypteringstype extends Activity {

public Button slider;
public Button krypterKnap;
public EditText tekst;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dekrypteringstype);                             // viser krypteringssiden
    slider = (Button) findViewById(R.id.handle);                            // forbinder xml-knappen og knappen "slider", som er defineret tidligere
    slider.getBackground().setAlpha(230);                                   // gør baggrunden, som jeg bruger let transparent
    //tekst = (EditText) findViewById(editText1);
    krypterKnap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dekrypter);
    krypterKnap.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            krypterKnap();
        }
    });
}

private void krypterKnap() {
    if (tekst.getText().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Skriv tekst først", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        konverter();
    }   
}

private void konverter(){
    String initialString = "yourString";
    char[] chars = initialString.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i)
        chars[i] = (char)((int)chars[i] + 2);
//  String resultString = new String(chars);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dekrypter, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

The XML for the activity above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/blue_binary_code_1600_1200"
tools:context=".Dekrypter" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dekrypter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_large"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="35dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:text="@string/valg"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/standardDekrypter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_large"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="35dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:text="@string/standard"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/overskriftDekrypter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_large"
    android:minHeight="35dp"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:text="@string/overskrift2"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/dekrypter"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/overskriftDekrypter"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerDekrypter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_large"
            android:minHeight="35dp"
            android:text="@string/ceasar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/ceasarNr"
                android:inputType="number" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_large"
            android:minHeight="35dp"
            android:text="@string/abe" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/a"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/b"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/e"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_large"
            android:minHeight="35dp"
            android:text="@string/rsa" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prim1"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prim2"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/k"
                android:inputType="number" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You uncommented the code that fetches the `tekst` input, so your app will crash when you try to to anything with the `tekst` variable

> //tekst = (EditText) findViewById(editText1);

That happens here:

```
...snip
 private void krypterKnap() {
        if (tekst.getText().equals("")){
...snip
```

so, uncomment `tekst = (EditText) findViewById(editText1);` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
I got the solution by following steps:
```

1. goto Windows-> Preferences-> XML-> XML Files
2. In Validation files section, choose Ignore in No grammar is specified, default is Warning
3. Apply and Ok. After Validating clean all projects and enjoy :)